# How to allow only IP address from a town to view a server

Tags: ip, server, html

I am trying to create a specific webpage, and I want to only allow people in my town to view it, so that later on I can expand on it and let surrounding towns view it. First, is this even possible, and second, if so, what language would be used to do this?

Answer (score 0):

An IP address does not provide that kind of information but there are [services out there](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=how%20to%20geolocate%20an%20ip%20address) that can "[geolocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation)" an address based on information they've collected.  I'm not sure [how accurate it will be](http://whatismyipaddress.com/geolocation-accuracy), though, so may not be able to identitify a specific town.